# How to ask someone how their diet is going

Tags: conversations, united-states, how-to-help

A bunch of my coworkers started a diet as part of their New Year's resolutions. I don't have much in common with most of them, and often have trouble finding topics for small talk. Since dieting is all the rage around my office, I figure that would be an easy thing to bring up, but I'm unsure how to go about it, as it *might* be a sensitive subject.

**What is the best way to ask someone how they are doing with their diet(s)?**

I have both male and female coworkers I could talk to about this, and some of them have started the same diet. Not sure if they're a team or if it's coincidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of asking *how their diet is going* (because this can imply you mean 'How much weight have you lost?), I'd recommend saying something like the following:

> "I heard you guys were trying out the **ketogenic** (replace with whatever fad diet name it is) diet. Do you like it?"

This way, you're only asking for an opinion from someone and giving *them* the option of how much to share with you. Additionally, asking for someones opinion on a topic is a great way to make small talk.

As another note, try to think of a generic comment you can make from your own point of view to show that you're not trying to pry.  For example, the ketogenic diet involves minimal carb intake, so I would say something like:

> "I heard you guys were trying out the ketogenic diet. Do you like it? It sounds interesting but I might love pasta too much for that!"

This puts the interest of the topic into them talking about the diet and not explicitly about their personal weight goals/achievements that they might not feel comfortable sharing with you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be careful here.  If it's someone you don't know well, and they aren't talking about it, I'd steer clear of this topic of conversation.  Put yourself in their position: out of the blue, someone you don't know very well asks "How's the diet going?"  Especially if you don't have a lot of other things to talk about, that can hurt interactions.

A better way to start a conversation would be to talk about New Year's resolutions.  People talk freely about them, and then you can ask (if they say something about a diet) how that is going.  Even asking "So, did you make any New Year's resolutions?  How are those going?" would be a less risky move than talking about a diet.

Comment: What if we're decent work friends? Or if they told me personally about their new diets?

Comment: If you're in a friendly relationship with that person, the chances for offense go down quite a bit (although they never disappear).  If they've told you about it, the occasional question is possible.  Keep in mind that NY resolutions last about a week or two, so this topic has a pretty short shelf life.  Additionally, I find any conversation involving someone else's age, weight, or measurement to not be worth the risk.